# How to remove div container in custom menu?

Tags: menus

all

```
       As per my html theme structure i do not want to add my menu <ul><li> under <div>.
```

I am using

```
 <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_class' => 'tlm', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
```

By default this wrap my menu with div.
like

```
<div class="menu-first-container"><ul class="tlm" id="menu-first"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23" id="menu-item-23"><a href="http://localhost/tmw_new/">Dashboard</a></li>
<li class="hasul menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-58" id="menu-item-58"><a href="#">Patients</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27" id="menu-item-27"><a href="http://localhost/tmw_new/?page_id=25">Patients</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-55 current_page_item menu-item-57" id="menu-item-57"><a href="http://localhost/tmw_new/?page_id=55">Add Patients</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-62" id="menu-item-62"><a href="http://localhost/tmw_new/?page_id=60">Calender</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-66" id="menu-item-66"><a href="http://localhost/tmw_new/?page_id=64">Images</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-67" id="menu-item-67"><a href="http://google.com">Support</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-68" id="menu-item-68"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

How to remove div container in custom menu ?
as i can think there may be need some change in wp_nav_menu() function array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the container to be empty. :)

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu_class' => 'tlm',
    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
    'container' => ''
) );
```

Please refer to the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to review all the arguments that you can pass to wp_nav_menu().

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parameter to remove the div container

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

there is a "container" class to change main container. you can change it to anything or put '' null to remove the container.

Comment: sorry its my fault that i am not defining 'container' => '' it. Without define this blank its take automatically div and its id. BTW thanks

Comment: one more think if u can help me ... as you can see li tag <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27" id="menu-item-27"><a href="http://localhost/tmw_new/?page_id=25">Patients</a></li>   i want to make it like <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27" id="menu-item-27"><a href="http://localhost/tmw_new/?page_id=25"><span>Patients</a></span></li>   (<span>)

Comment: did it using  'link_before'     => ,
  'link_after'      => ,